# react native expo video player white statusbar on full creen

Tags: react-native, expo

i use expo av and if i click on full screen then my statusbar is white. But Why?

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, Dimensions, SafeAreaView, Button } from 'react-native';
import pure from 'recompose/pure';
import { Video, AVPlaybackStatus } from 'expo-av';

const { height, width } = Dimensions.get('window');

const Product_stack_video = ({ uri }) => {
  const video = useRef(null);
  return (
      <Video
        ref={video}
        shouldPlay={true}
        style={styles.video}
        source={{
          uri: uri || 'http://d23dyxeqlo5psv.cloudfront.net/big_buck_bunny.mp4',
        }}
        useNativeControls
        resizeMode="contain"
        
        isLooping
        style={{height: 500, width}}
      />
  )
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width: '100%',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  video: {
    width: '100%',
    height: 400,
  },
});

export default pure(Product_stack_video);
```

......................................................................
...........................................................................
.................................................................................[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the statusBar to 'hidden' explicitly